# Monster stat block and magic weapons +1

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monster-design

Let's suppose I want to give to one monster a magic weapon +1 (for example a greatsword +1). How should I indicate it in the monster stat block? Should I write in the actions section something like this?

> ***Greatsword +1.*** *Melee Weapon Attack*: +prof bonus+str mod+1 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. *Hit*: (2d6 + str mod+1) slashing damage.

I can't find anywhere a precise answer to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mirt from *Waterdeep: Dragonheist* has a +1 Longsword, and his attack action reads:

> ***+1 Longsword.** Melee Weapon Attack:* +9 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. *Hit:* 14 (2d8 + 5) slashing damage, or 16 (2d10 + 5) slashing damage when used with two hands.

The bonuses to hit and damage compute as expected based on his strength (+4), proficiency (+4), and bonus from the Longsword (+1). He also has a trait in his statblock that reads:

> ***Special Equipment.*** Mirt wears bracers of defense and a ring of regeneration. He wields a longsword, +1 and a dagger, +1.

His damage dice are 2d8 (2d10 versatile) because of his Brute feature:

> ***Brute.*** A melee weapon deals one extra die of its damage when Mirt hits with it (included in the attacks below).

Comment: This is a great example. In general, the principle seems to be to streamline the stat blocks from a DM'ing perspective as much as possible: The DM should at most be presented with just a *XdY+Z* formula, that is, some dice to roll and a single modifier to add. The less calculations the DM has to perform on the fly the easier it is to run the game smoothly while fielding such monster. The more a DM has to hunt down extra modifiers the more likely is it to either bog down the game or just end up being overlooked.